# how to invoke an application packaged inside a bundled virtual environment with spark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

i have a python repository that i bundled into a virtual environment with `poetry bundle venv` that is then pushed to AWS S3. Inside this virtual environment exists a script named `test.py`. I want to know how to run `spark-submit` with `test.py` as my application:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --packages MYPACKAGES --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python3 --archives s3://MYBUCKET/PATH/TO/MY_REPO.tar.gz#environment --py-files ./environment/lib/python3/site-packages/MY_REPO/test.py test.py
```

I tried placing my `test.py` in my PYTHONPATH with the `--py-files` argument but i still get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/hadoop/lollerskates/test.py does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:832)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:341)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.copyFileToRemote(Client.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.distribute$1(Client.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:983)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1339)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1776)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1006)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1104)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

im running spark 3.3.2, python3.10 on AWS EMR 6.11 machines